# How to get particular key and value in array of objects

Tags: javascript

sample array

```
let arr = [
{
    "name": "header-fs",
    "header-fs": "font-style",
}, {
    "name": "header-ff",
    "header-ff": "font-family",
}, {
    "name": "content-fs",
    "content-fs": 'font-style',
}, {
    "name": "content-ff",
    "content-ff": "font-family",
}];
```

// sStyle = header-fs

```
findStyle(sStyle) { 
        let sSelected;
        arr.forEach((obj) => {
            if (obj.name === sStyle) {
                sSelected = obj[sStyle];
            }
        });
        return sSelected;  //font-style
 }
```

//  sAattribute - content (either header or content)

```
 //   sStyle      - font-style

findKey(sAattribute, sStyle) {
    let sSelected;
        arr.forEach((obj) => {
            for (var prop in obj) {
                if (prop.includes(sAattribute)) {
                    if (obj[prop] === sStyle)
                        sSelected = prop;
                }
            }
        });
        return sSelected;   //content-fs
    }
```

The Above two functions are working fine
Actually it is a small data i real time the data is more

any help

thanks in advance

Comment: You are asking `how to avoid this problem`, but you do not describe the problem. I could only guess...

Comment: code simplification.  for two functions (findStyle and findKey ) here data is very less . Actually data is more

Comment: why not just using `find` here `arr.find(k=>Object.values(k).includes('font-style'))?.name`

Comment: @srikanth This is still not a description of the problem.

Comment: @gorak This would not improve performance, it only makes the code shorter.

Comment: @kai seems this is what OP wants. *code simplification*

Comment: @gorak Since he is always pointing out that `actual data is more`, i thought he is talking about performance.

Comment: @kai your solution is perfect. it is shorter and takes care of performance.